# How to get file size of objects from google cloud python library?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

### Problem

Hello everyone. I am attempting to obtain the file size of an object using the `google-cloud` python library. This is my current code.

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket("example-bucket-name")
object = bucket.blob("example-object-name.jpg")

print(object.exists())
>>> True

print(object.chunk_size)
>>> None
```

It appears to me that the `google-cloud` library is choosing not to load data into the attributes such as `chunk_size`, `content_type`, etc.

### Question

How can I make the library explicitly load actual data into the metadata attributes of the blob, instead of defaulting everything to `None`?

Comment: this question did not need the `python` and `python-3.x` tags since this is not a python issue, per se.

Comment: @Skaperen agreed, removed the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `get_blob` instead of `blob`.

Review the source code for the function `blob_metadata` at [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/storage_get_metadata.py). It shows how to get a variety of metadata attributes of a blob, including its size.

If the above link dies, try looking around in this directory: [Storage Client Samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/cloud-client)

Comment: Will `get_blob` also download the contents of the file? Or will it only retrieve the metadata?

Comment: To download the object, call `download_to_filename()`, `download_as_string()` or similar type of function. These are documented. https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/  and https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html

Comment: @JohnHanley your link is dead, sadly.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 6):

Call `size` on `Blob`.

```
from google.cloud import storage

# create client
client: storage.client.Client = storage.Client('projectname')

# get bucket
bucket: storage.bucket.Bucket = client.get_bucket('bucketname')

size_in_bytes = bucket.get_blob('filename').size
```

Comment: @SuperEye - The code works. I just verified that on my system. Change the projectname, bucketname, and filename. No issues. What problem did you experience?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, bucket.get_blob('filename').size works fine.